# Why the image is null?

Tags: c#, winforms

In form1 constructor

```
bitmapwithclouds = new Bitmap(@"D:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\Resources\test.png");
cleanradar = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.clean_radar_image);
CloudEnteringAlert.CloudsOnly(bitmapwithclouds, Properties.Resources.clean_radar_image);
pictureBox3.Image = CloudEnteringAlert.newbitmap;
```

In the class CloudEnteringAlert I have the method CloudsOnly:

```
public static Bitmap CloudsOnly(Bitmap bitmapwithclouds, Bitmap bitmapwithoutclouds)
        {
            tolerancenumeric = 15;
            Color backgroundColor = Color.Black; 
            int tolerance = tolerancenumeric * tolerancenumeric + tolerancenumeric * tolerancenumeric + tolerancenumeric * tolerancenumeric; 
            Bitmap newbitmap = new Bitmap(512, 512); 
            for (int x = 0; x < bitmapwithclouds.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < bitmapwithclouds.Height; y++)
                {
                    Color color1 = bitmapwithclouds.GetPixel(x, y);
                    Color color2 = bitmapwithoutclouds.GetPixel(x, y);
                    Color color = Color.Black;

                    int dR = (int)color2.R - (int)color1.R;
                    int dG = (int)color2.G - (int)color1.G;
                    int dB = (int)color2.B - (int)color1.B;
                    int error = dR * dR + dG * dG + dB * dB;


                    if ((x == 479) && (y == 474))
                    {
                        color = Color.Black;
                    }

                    if (error < tolerance)
                    {

                        color = backgroundColor;

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        color = color1; 

                    }
                    newbitmap.SetPixel(x, y, color);
                }
            }
            newbitmap.Save(@"d:\test\newbitmap.jpg");
            return newbitmap;
        }

In the middle of the method im using getpixel and setpixel.
```

I used a breakpoint and I see that after its doing return newbitmap so newbitmap is NOT null.

But in for1 on the line:

```
pictureBox3.Image = CloudEnteringAlert.newbitmap;
```

The Image is null.

In the method CloudEnteringAlert i added newbitmap as static in the top of the class.
In the method CloudsOnly i make instance for the bitmap.
I also see the file after its saving it on the hard disk.

```
public static Bitmap newbitmap;
```

So why its null when i assign it to picturebox3 ?

Comment: Show the whole relevant code instead of describing it. Also, the code you posted doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `newbitmap` in the below code is a local variable, it will never be accessible from outside this method let alone from another class.

You are returning it in the end but the calling code calls this function like a procedure, the result is lost.

I guess you also have a `public CloudEnteringAlert.newbitmap` property or field but it is being masked by the local variable with the same name.

```
public static Bitmap CloudsOnly(Bitmap bitmapwithclouds, Bitmap bitmapwithoutclouds)
{
    ...
    Bitmap newbitmap = new Bitmap(512, 512);   // local variable
    ...
    return newbitmap;
}
```

The shortest (not the most elegant) patch is:

```
public static void CloudsOnly(Bitmap bitmapwithclouds, Bitmap bitmapwithoutclouds)
{
    ...
    //Bitmap newbitmap = new Bitmap(512, 512);   // local variable
    newbitmap = new Bitmap(512, 512);            // class member 
    ...
    // return newbitmap;
}
```

Comment: Check the last line of the function.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - yes, but that doesn't match the calling code. I was already editing.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't ever actually assigning `pictureBox3.Image`. You create a new one in your method and return it, but you don't do anything with it. Change your code so that the `newbitmap` will get returned into your picturebox.

```
pictureBox3.Image =  CloudEnteringAlert.CloudsOnly(bitmapwithclouds,Properties.Resources.clean_radar_image);
```